# Nmap bash dynamic create files

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, nmap

I'm doing a script that uses `nmap` to get all the devices on a *ip* address range and their *mac* address. I want to create a file for each device, like *IPaddress_macaddress*.
I did that to get the values but I don't know how I can dynamically create files.

```
sudo nmap -n -sP 192.168.1.* | 
awk '/Nmap scan report/{printf $5;printf " ";getline;getline;printf $3;}' > file.txt
```

This prints on file.txt :

```
192.168.1.10 DC:EX:03:0S:4B:31
192.168.1.11 A4:2G:8C:E8:5A:65
192.168.1.32 9C:80:GF:J0:53:6F
192.168.1.23 64:7C:54:CC:SD:C4
192.168.1.77 256
```

The format of this file is

```
ipaddress macaddress
```

I want to parse that file to create for each line a new file with the name of the content of each line, adding an underscore between the ipaddress and the macaddress. To correspond to *ipaddress_macaddress.txt*

So, for that file.txt, with a script, I want it to create 
*192.168.1.10_DC:EX:03:0S:4B:31.txt* etc

I don't know how can I parse it intelligently

Comment: Can you not just redirect the output to a file e.g. by adding > filename

Comment: @RamanSailopal Yes I can easily redirect the output to a file but how can I parse it easily to save ips and mac to values?

Comment: You're asking for help to write an awk script that converts some input text to some output text so you have to show us what that input and output looks like. [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input (ie. the output of your `nmap` command) and the expected output given that input. If the desired output is multiple files, which it sounds like it might be, then obviously show us at least 2 output files with their contents. The correct answer will not use getline btw, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline, and never do `printf $<anything>`.

Comment: Ok I followed your advices to edit my post. Thank you.

Comment: No, you followed half my advice. Maybe. You posted the expected output but you still haven't posted the input that would produce that output. Actually I'm not even sure if what you posted is the output you **do** want or the output you currently get that you **don't** want. You do NOT need an intermediate script with it's own associated output file to get from the `nmap` output to the final output files you want. Please just show us sample input (the `nmap` output) and the final expected output and again, see [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ls
file

$ while read ip mac; do touch ${ip}_${mac}.txt; done < file

$ ls
192.168.1.10_DC:EX:03:0S:4B:31.txt  192.168.1.23_64:7C:54:CC:SD:C4.txt 192.168.1.77_256.txt
192.168.1.11_A4:2G:8C:E8:5A:65.txt  192.168.1.32_9C:80:GF:J0:53:6F.txt  file
```

Answer (score 1):

As an awk onliner you could do:

```
nmap -n -sP 192.168.1.* | awk '{ if ($0 ~ /Nmap scan/) { ip=$5 } if ($0 ~ /MAC/) { mac=$3;det[mac]=ip } } END { for ( i in det ) { system("echo \""i" "det[i]"\" > "i"_"det[i]".txt") } }'
```

This will take the output from nmap and then search for "Nmap scan" and place the ip address in the variable ip and then "MAC" placing the mac address in mac. An array is then created with the ip address and the MAC address. This is then looped through and the awk system function is utilised to create the files with the ip and MAC addresses.